# Replacement for standard KDE monitor manager?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, kde, monitors

My Linux experience is roughly a 4/10.  I'm running the latest Debian-Wheezy install, and I've been having some trouble with the stock KDE display/monitor manager (to clarify as these terms seem to converge - referring to the utility that manages the monitors, resolution, etc.; not KDE itself).  From googling the issue, I'm not alone in having problems docking the laptop, trying to run on two external monitors, etc., and the display manager freezing up.

I've found a workaround for the application locking up, but it's kind of annoying, and I'd like to see if there's another display manager out there I can use.  I've never replaced a core function in a Linux distro before, so A) I'm looking for some feedback on the best alternative(s) out there to the stock display manager, and B) Need some help in removing the current utility from the environment.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The display manager is the application where you type your password before logging in. Nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What's called the [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_manager) is not what you think it is, and investigating that will not solve your problems.

You seem to hint at a specific issue:

> having problems docking the laptop, trying to run on two external monitors

But you'll have to be more explicit; this could be a kernel driver issue or an Xorg issue.

It might also be a KDE issue, but KDE is not really responsible for managing hardware; it is a layer on top of the X server.  However, it does configure the X server (and reconfigure via the "Systems Settings" interface). In that case, it may be as simple as just tweaking X yourself, but again, you'll have to be specific about what your problems are and what your hardware is.

Comment: Understood.  What is the correct term for the utility that manages the displays?

Is there an alternative to the built in utility in KDE?

Comment: There is no "built in utility" in KDE besides a user interface for configuring the X server.  You could change that (although I doubt there are alternatives, since they would be mostly pointless), but if it is an X problem it won't help.  Analogy: changing your steering wheel won't fix your engine. If it is that KDE is configuring X wrongly, then you have to determine that by playing with the X configuration manually.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have been having some trouble with XServer, so I'll go back to the drawing board then.  Thanks to all for the help.